# Take user input from scanf and add to a array?

Tags: objective-c, arrays, scanf

I'm trying to create an array of questions that I will enter into a trivia game. I'm having problems with scanf and adding the whole questions to the array. It will only enter the first word of my question

Example: I want to input "How many bases in baseball?" and have it entered into allquestions[0], then be asked for the next questions to be entered into the array, but what I get is just "How" from scanf. I think I need to transfer the scanf input into a string then addobject into the array. 
Any help would be much appreciated. I'm very new to this.

```
        NSMutableArray *allquestions = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

        char *questions[200];
        int i =0;
        for (i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
            NSLog(@"Next question?");
            scanf("%s",&questions);

            NSLog(@"%s", &questions);
            [allquestions addObject:questions[i]];
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope it will work for you:

```
NSMutableArray *allquestions = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
char questions[20][200]; // Can store 20 questions each of length 200

//input each question
for(int i=0;i<20;i++)
{
   NSLog(@"Next question?");
   scanf("%[^\n]%*c",questions[i]);
   NSString *questionString = [NSString stringWithCString:questions[i] encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];

   [allquestions addObject:questionString];

}

//Print each string
for(int i=0;i<20;i++)
{
   printf("%s",questions[i]);
   printf("\n");
}
```

Comment: I get an error with [allquestions addObject:questions[i]];  Implicit conversion of a non-Objective-C pointer type 'char *' to 'id_Nonnull' is disallowed with ARC, and Incompatible pointer types sending 'char [200] to parameter of type 'id_Nonnull'

Comment: Let me know in case still you are facing any issues? I have tried running this code and it is working fine.

Comment: Thank you for the help. Now it is saving each word in the question instead of the whole questions. So, if i ask "How many bases in baseball?". It saves "How", "many", "bases", "in", "baseball?", instead of the whole question. When you ask that question it runs the loop the number of words you have in the question. So, this example would ask "Next question?" 5 times.

Comment: yes you are right. Just replace  `scanf("%s",questions[i]);` with `scanf("%[^\n]%*c",questions[i]);`. in first loop. I have already updated the code.

It takes input till newline ('\n') comes.